# flask return not working with post jquery request in html code

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, datatables

I'm having an issue where a form is being submitted via a jquery post.  I am manipulating form data and need to submit specific data.  I am unable to use the built in POST as multiple pages are not getting submitted with the dataTables plugin so I have to modify the data in the javascript before submission. The code below is working in that the code in 'url_for('aws_execute')' is being executed, but the page is not loading in the browser.

So in this example, '123' would get printed to the python console, but the website would not get redirected, and "test please work" would not show in the browser.

If I do a function after the post, I am able to get information such as a console log or a alert, but am not sure how to get the page to redirect as I want to have a new page show results and not an alert, etc.  Any ideas how this can be done?

Thanks!

<aws_options.html page>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
      <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/jquery.dataTables.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery-3.5.1.js') }}"></script>
      <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#options').on('submit', function(e){
              // Prevent actual form submission
              e.preventDefault();

              var data = table.$('input,select,textarea').serializeArray();
              var data2 = $(this).serializeArray();
              var data3 = $.merge(data,data2);

not working--->$.post({
                 url: '{{ url_for('aws_execute') }}',
                 data: data3

              },
              function(data3,status){
                     alert("Data: " + data3 + "\nStatus: " + status);
              });
          });

      } );
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>

<h1>AWS Options</h1>
<form id="options" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('aws_execute') }}">
  <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
  (FORM STUFF)
</body>
</html>
```

In python:

```
@app.route('/aws_execute', methods=['POST'])
@saml_manager.login_required
def aws_execute():
    print('123')
    return 'test please work'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's in Javascript, you just need to simply use the route itself. No need to use url_for().

```
$.post({
  url: '/aws_execute',
  data: data3
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.post` makes an AJAX request, so any response to it will not be automatically rendered. If your intention is to have the response to your `POST` request render, why not allow the form to follow its default behavior (i.e. get rid of all of that jQuery)?

Otherwise, if you want it to be AJAX, you need to include a callback to specify what do with the data in your response after you get it. For example, try this and see if it logs `test please work` to your browser console:

```
$.post({
  '{{ url_for('aws_execute') }}',
  data3,
  responseData => console.log(responseData)
});
```

Comment: That callback works, however i'm not sure how to get it to goto the next page, since I want to do some more advanced things than doing an alert or console log.  I am unable to just use the default post because I need to manipulate the form data due to issues with the dataTables plugin.   any advice?

Comment: You could include `window.replace(<url>)` inside your callback.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/aws_execute', methods=['POST'])
@saml_manager.login_required
def aws_execute():
    print('123')
    return render_template(url_for('aws_execute'))
```